# Crawler-transporter's ground pressure?

Tags: crawler-transporter

How many PSI does the [CT-2 crawler](https://www.nasa.gov/content/the-crawlers) carrying the [Artemis I](https://www.nasa.gov/artemis-1) rocket exert on the ground?
How does that [compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure#Examples) to more conventional vehicles?

NASA's [fact sheet](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/combined_crawler-transporters_fact_sheet_final.pdf) mentions relevant weights, and that each corner of the crawler has a two-belt truck, but it omits the footprint of the 8 belts.

Comment: There is a possible upper bound stated in a test of the crawlerway foundation. One shoe in the track is 1620 in^2 and is required to carry up to 500,000 lb, which works out to about 300 psi. https://www.nasa.gov/missions/shuttle/crawler_shoes.html https://www.jonesedmunds.com/portfolio-works/nasa-crawlerway-foundation-compatibility-study/

Comment: From photos, 1620 in^2 looks plausible, say 9 ft by a bit more than 1 ft.  If you can cite that, then we just count the number of shoes on the ground, and we're done.  I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: Moonport says each shoe is 0.3x2.3 meters with 57 shoes per track. (Page 274)

Comment: @Ludo the link I cited (assuming I converted it right, always a shaky assumption) gives 0.46 x 2.3 meters. Not sure why the discrepancy, both are NASA sources. I know the shoes were replaced at least once, but I assumed the "footprint" didn't change, that could also be wrong.

Comment: Here's my best personal photo of a crawler track. I count 22 shoes on the ground. https://i.imgur.com/BQEJuRm.jpg  Taken in 2008.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'll take a stab at answering, since I think we have enough info (going to be borrowing that photo, it's great)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I noticed the discrepancy too. The width dimensions agree, the half-foot difference in length may be due to including/excluding the link that connects the shoes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [differing](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/shuttle/crawler_shoes.html) [sources](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4204/ch13-1.html), the shoes are either 7.5 feet x 1.5 feet (2.286 meters x 0.4572 meters) or 0.3 meters x 2.3 meters (7.54593 feet x 0.984252 feet), for an area between 1620 in<sup>2</sup> and 1070 in<sup>2</sup>  which is a bit of a range, but workable.

Given a [500,000 lb](https://www.jonesedmunds.com/portfolio-works/nasa-crawlerway-foundation-compatibility-study/) load test, that gives an upper bound to the between 308 PSI and 467 PSI, but that's the design per-shoe and not the capacity or weight of the system.

According to [this page](https://www.nasa.gov/content/the-crawlers), the crawler itself weighs "Approximately 6.6 million pounds", with a maximum load of 18 million pounds, while [this sheet](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/combined_crawler-transporters_fact_sheet_final.pdf) lists the Artemis I launch vehicle at "Approximately 3.5 million pounds" and ML-1 (Mobile Launcher-1) as "Approximately 11.3 million pounds".  That gives us a total weight of 21.4 million pounds for Artemis 1, with a max design weight of 24.6 million pounds.

Thanks to Organic Marble for the wonderful [picture of the crawler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulTef.jpg), where I agree with his count of 22 shoes on the ground at a time.  With 22 shoes per track and 8 tracks per crawler, that gives 176 total shoes.

| Shoe area | Artemis I | At Maximum Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1620 in<sup>2</sup> | 75.1 PSI | 86.3 PSI |
| 1070 in<sup>2</sup> | 114 PSI | 131 PSI |

Taking a few of the the examples of [ground pressures from the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure#Examples),

| Object | Ground pressure (psi) |
| --- | --- |
| Stiletto heel | 471 |
| Road racing bicycle | 90 |
| Mountain bicycle | 40 |
| Adult elephant | 35 |
| Passenger car | 30 |

Unless my math above is heinously wrong, the ground pressure would seem to be within the range of some common vehicles.

Comment: I think you need to add the weight of ML-1 as well

Comment: @Ludo ah, there's my heinously wrong math!  Also, thanks for the mention of Moonport.  1 moment re-doing some math (at least those maximum capacity calculations should be right)

Comment: Turns out that it puts it a lot closer to the maximum capacity (which makes sense), which would explain why it seemed a bit ... *light* ... when I was doing the math.